# base::plot -- can I retrieve the as-plotted aspect ratio?

Tags: r, plot

I know I can specify the aspect ratio when plotting, e.g. `plot(x,y,asp=5)` . Is there any way to retrieve the aspect ratio after allowing autoscale (as in `plot(x,y)`) ?  The reason I ask is that I was playing with `text(x,y,'mystring',srt=local_slope)` , where I calculate the `local_slope` based on the underlying curve and the `x` value of interest.  Trouble is, for `asp!=1` this rotates the text at a different angle from the displayed slope of my plotted data set.   Sample:

```
x<- -10:10
y<- x^2
plot(x,y,t='l',asp=0.1) 
# the slope at x=1 is 2 but the default plot aspect ratio is far from 1:1
text(1,1,'foo',srt= 180/pi*atan(2) )  #ugly-looking
text(-1,1,'bar',srt= (180/pi*atan(2/10))) #better
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
x<- -10:10
y<- x^2
plot(x,y,t='l',asp=0.1) 
### the slope at x=1 is 2 but the default plot aspect ratio is far from 1:1
text(1,1,'foo',srt= 180/pi*atan(2) )  #ugly-looking
text(-1,1,'bar',srt= (180/pi*atan(2/10))) #better
```

Get width and height of plotting region in inches ...

```
ff <- par("pin")
ff[2]/ff[1]  ## 1.00299
```

Now resize the plot manually ...

```
ff <- par("pin")
ff[2]/ff[1]  ## 0.38
```

You can also use `par("usr")` to sort out the aspect ratio
in user units, but I haven't figured out quite the right
set of ratios ...  the guts of `MASS::eqscplot` might be enlightening too.

Comment: Thanks.  I can generate `myasp <-ff[2]/ff[1]*diff(range(y))/diff(range(x))` . //   I suspect several of the advanced plotting packages deal w/ this; I just haven't got that far yet :-)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft -- `range(y)` and `range(x)` don't necessarily give the full range of values covered by the y and x axes. They won't, for example, when `par(xaxs="r")` -- R's default. So it's probably safer to do the equivalent of `myasp <- with(par(), (pin[2]/pin[1])/(diff(usr[3:4])/diff(usr[1:2])))`

Comment: @JoshO'Brien  thanks- I'll be more cautious about my calculation.